# gnuradio OOT module xml file has parsing errors

Tags: xml, gnuradio

I followed the wiki https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python#3.2.1._Using_gr_modtool to generate a OOT module and install it. No issues with this step. 
However, I am facing an issue while running gnuradio-companion. I get the following errors.

```
pradmc$ gnuradio-companion 

(process:64731): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:21:34.591: Locale not supported by C library.   Using the fallback 'C' locale. <<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.7.13.4 >>>

Block paths:    /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc   /opt/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks

Loading: "/Users/pradmc/gnuradio/serial/serial.grc"
>>> Done

Loading: "/Users/pradmc/gnuradio/serial_test.grc"
>>> Done

XML parser: Found 1 erroneous XML file while loading the block tree (see "Help/Parser errors" for details)
```

It says there is one erroneous XML file. I confirmed it is because of my module. Without my module i don't see the error. 
My module's xml is a very simple with one source and one sink.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<block>
  <name>constant_gen_ii</name>
  <key>constant_gen_ii_constant_gen_ii</key>
  <category>Misc</category>
  <import>import constant_gen_ii</import>
  <make>constant_gen_ii.constant_gen_ii($max)</make>
  <!-- Make one 'param' node for every Parameter you want settable from the GUI.
       Sub-nodes:
       * name
       * key (makes the value accessible as $keyname, e.g. in the make node)
       * type -->
  <param>
    <name>max</name>
    <key>max</key>
    <type>int</type>
  </param>

  <--- Make one 'sink' node per input. Sub-nodes:
       * name (an identifier for the GUI)
       * type
       * vlen
       * optional (set to 1 for optional inputs) -->
  <sink>
    <name>in</name>
    <type>int</type>
  </sink>

  <!-- Make one 'source' node per output. Sub-nodes:
       * name (an identifier for the GUI)
       * type
       * vlen
       * optional (set to 1 for optional inputs) -->
  <source>
    <name>out</name>
    <type>int</type>
  </source>
</block>
```

How do I know what were the parser errors? 
I am not sure what is wrong with the above XML.

Regards,
Pradeep M C

Comment: what do the `Parser Error` in the `Help` menu say?

Comment: Oh, and the syntax highlighting in the editor solved this. What's the color of a comment in the XML syntax highlighting on this site? What's the color of your middle XML comment?

Comment: Overlooked it completely!!!! :( Thanks for pointing it out @Marcus. May be I should use an IDE with syntax highlighting instead of good old VIM :(

Comment: vim has awesome syntax highlighting, but you need to use the right plugins

Comment: try installing the awesome version of [this](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) (follow instructions!) and you get a really impressive set of tools.